# Listing out items in React/NextJS with Bootstrap cards

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, next.js, bootstrap-5

My problem is that when I list out my items using cards with bootstrap doesn't matter how I try the cards are always going to be under each other not next to each other. Could someone help me figure it out?

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { urlFor } from '../lib/client'



const Product = ({product: { image, name, details, slug, price}}) => {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
    <div className='row'>
      <div className='col-sm-4 col-lg-4'>
     <div className='card-group'>
      <div className="card bg-transparent text-light border-light m-2 ">
      <div className="card-body text-center ">
       <Link href={`/product/${slug.current}`}>
          <img className=' bg-transparent img-fluid' src={urlFor(image && image[0])}></img>
          </Link>
          <h5 className="card-title text-light  text-decoration-none">{name}</h5>
           <p className="card-text text-light text-decoration-none">{details}</p>
          <p className='card-text text-light text-decoration-none'>{price} HUF Br.</p>
          <Link href={`/product/${slug.current}`}><button className='btn btn-outline-light btn-lg'>Érdekel</button></Link>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Product
```

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). The card group is placed in a div.row and that keeps the card in a row of the grid. Try removing the div.container and div.row ancestors. Ensure that the Ancestor of `Product` in the React element tree renders them though.

Comment: Did you inspect the output in the browser? It should be fairly apparent what went wrong.